# Laravel 6 not sending the correct password reset link in heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-6, change-password, password-recovery

I have an app that has a database server in laravel 6 on heroku, and I am fairly new to laravel. I have made it in such a way that the user can only register login via the mobile app and only the password reset functionality works through the URLs. I have tested the password reset functionality locally and its working fine but it is on heroku that I am getting the wrong links in the email. My app url is

```
http://myAppName.herokuapp.com
```

hence the password reset form link is at

```
http://myAppName.herokuapp.com/password/reset
```

the routes defined in the web.php file to have the password reset functionality are

```
    Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```

But when I am testing password reset on heroku I am getting the reset links as

```
http://myAppName.herokuapp.com/myAppName.herokuapp.com/password/reset/{token}
```

istead of

```
http://myAppName.herokuapp.com/password/reset/{token}
```

what I should be getting. Can anyone be kind enough to tell me why I am getting this link instead of the expected link and how do I fix it on heroku

Comment: Bro can you show your Email code ?

Comment: its the default, havent edited that

Comment: to be honest im a bit new to laravel so I dont think I know the location for the default emails file

Comment: any solutions to solve the issue?

Comment: It seems like configuration issue during upload

Comment: Verify your env file , It might have someunwanted changes